# Vertical short dash

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am searching for vertical short dash (similar to `\vdash`) but couldn't find one. `Fourier` and `mathpazo` packages do contain this symbol but there is no corresponding macro defined.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a vertical bar the same size as `\vdash`, you can build it using `picture` mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\medmid}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\med@mid\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\med@mid}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\vdash$}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\ht\z@}%
  \begin{picture}(.3,1)
  \roundcap
  \linethickness{%
    \ifdim\unitlength<0.9ex
      0.08%
    \else
    \ifdim\unitlength<1.2ex
      0.07%
    \else
      0.06%
    \fi
  \fi\unitlength}
  \polyline(.2,0.03)(.2,0.97)
  \end{picture}%
}


\begin{document}

$\medmid\vdash$\qquad $a\medmid b\mid c$

$\scriptstyle\medmid\vdash$

$\scriptscriptstyle\medmid\vdash$

\end{document}
```

[image]